# How to get a list of commits affecting files in a certain directory on Github on deleted branch in Node GitHub Action

Tags: git, github, github-actions, octokit-js

I have a mono repo and I want to figure out "per package" diff in Github actions.

I'm using `git rev-list --format=%aN%cN%B <from-tag>..HEAD -- packages/<name>`, which is working fine and giving all commits to analyse.

However, some of commits are squashed using default Github notation (ends with PR number `(#1234)`). In this case I want to "unsquash" the commit by replacing it with all commits in PR (with directory filter).

So I was trying to use `@octokit/rest` for this to obtain PR `base` and `head` SHAs like following:

```js
import { Octokit } from '@octokit/rest'
import get from 'lodash/get'

const octokit = new Octokit()

const pr = await octokit.rest.pulls.get({
    owner: '<owner-name>',
    repo: '<repo-name>',
    pull_number: <pull-number>,
})
const baseSha = get(pr, ['data', 'base', 'sha'], null)
const headSha = get(pr, ['data', 'head', 'sha'], null)
```

And then running the same command above, but for a different range: `git rev-list --format=%aN%cN%B <baseSha>..<headSha>-- packages/<name>`.

The problem is after Squash and Merge PRs some branches can be deleted. So, they're not  available for git.

It seems that there are two ways to go here:

1. Somehow tell the git about the deleted branches
2. Get this information from octokit

The first option sounds impossible, so the question is:

Is there a way to obtain this information in simple way, like `git rev-list` does (no sub-request for each commit to receive file list)?